# Cursor jumps around while typing, Fn+F3 to disable touchpad also not working on an Asus EEE PC 1015PE

Tags: touchpad

Jumping cursor while typing on my Asus EEE PC 1015PE.  Keyboard shortcut--Function key plus F3 also not working, as well as a few other function keys not working.  Would appreciate any help.  Note: mouse/touchpad "Disable touchpad while typing" setting is enabled, but does not work.

Comment: perennial problem on my mba, bookmarked

Answer (score 1):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/options.conf
```

Add this line to the file and save it:

> options psmouse proto=imps

Restart.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/355326/comments/9

Comment: I created the above file with the "options psmouse proto=imps" and the touchpad settings completely disappeared from the Mouse/Touchpad system settings. Now only mouse settings remain. The

Comment: I removed the options.conf.  Restarted.  It feels like the problem is gone.  No more jumping cursor and the touchpad settings returned to the Mouse/Touchpad system settings app.  Hypothesis: It could have been a faulty touchpad driver installation, which was removed with the creation of the options.conf file.  When I removed the file, the touchpad driver reinstalled, probably correctly.  So, indirectly, the above instructions led to a true fix, which was actually an initially faulty touchpad driver configuration, now corrected.  Thanks for the help for the solution.  MH

Comment: A dirty solution, but it is still a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling mouse/touchpad "Disable touchpad while typing" setting and maybe it will help with that couse anyway u say it doesnt work so maybe thats why it jumps couse doesnt work. Also try again enabling. and restart after each try.

If doesnt help leave as disabled that option and install Touchfreeze from ubuntu soft manager. If on reboot it doesnt work automatically then put it to be starting on startup in System > Preferences > Sessions startup programms with adding new and writing command in there touchfreeze

Comment: Cursor still jumps after applying above "fix which also made all of the touchpad settings disappear from the Mouse/Touchpad system settings app.  so, I can't attempt the second "fix" as touchpad options are gone.  My search for fix continues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solution was to install SYNAPTIKS from the Ubuntu 11.10 repo. Worked well, no-more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the <kbd>FN</kbd> key and the <kbd>f</kbd> buttons, obviously not those marked for general use like brightness or sound.

I just found that if I use the <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>f5</kbd> buttons on my laptop it stops the touchpad. I had tried various other things to deactivate it, from unistalling to diabling to downloading software; then came across this post and yeahhhh it works like magic. :-)